Matlab/Simulink Parallel Computing with Initialization Scripts
The variables that my model needs are mostly structures: say, struct1, struct2, etc..  The model then accesses their fields as inputs to different masks.  Whether using parsim or parfor/sim, I need to run an initialization scripts with different inputs to the script and this main script also calls a bunch of subroutines.  A non-parallel workflow is as follows:

Change input parameters: param1, param2, etc.
Execute the main initialization script (calling other scripts)
Modified structures: struct1, struct2, etc. are available in the Workspace
Run the model
Repeat Steps 1 through 4 with another set of values for param1, param2, etc.

I tried to use set_param to assign the fields of the structures to the masks inside a parfor first to put together a simin before executing parsim, but it seems to hate executing the main initialization script before I can even use them for set_param.  I tried using parsim, but basically the same approach.  Thus, it fails in a similar manner.
How do I convert the non-parallel workflow listed above to a parallel computing scheme?
